# How to pad a numpy 3D array (or torch tensor) with values from surrounding 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, pytorch

I have a 3D numpy array of shape `3,3,3` to which I want to pad 2 layers of values from arrays surrounding it spatially, so that it becomes a `5,5,5` array.

[image]

What I have done so far using torch cat function (which works the same as numpy concat) to pad the y array, is the following:

```
x = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(1,28,1).reshape(3,3,3))
y = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(28,55,1).reshape(3,3,3))
z = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(55,82,1).reshape(3,3,3))

torch.cat((y,z[:,:2,:]), dim=1) #To concat z+ with 2 pads
torch.cat((x[:,1:,:],y), dim=1) #To concat z- with 2 pads

torch.cat((y,z[:,:,:2]), dim=2) #To concat x+ with 2 pads
torch.cat((x[:,1:,:],y), dim=1) #To concat x- with 2 pads

torch.cat((x,z[:2,:,:]), dim=2) #To concat y+ with 2 pads
torch.cat((x[1:,:,:],y), dim=1) #To concat y- with 2 pads
```

But it does not give me the right values. How can I acheive this?

Comment: If I follow correctly, the operation you propose results in an non-rectangular shape (basically a 5x5x5 cube but missing the edges and corners) with 81 elements. A 5x5x5 tensor has 125 elements. For example what value would you expect the resulting tensor to have at index (0,0,0)? If you can provide an example input/output that would help a lot.

Comment: @jodag I see your point. The edges and corner areas will be left behind. Actually, I have no idea. The problem is that i need to make a function that takes the desired number of layers from all the touching boxes/arrays and concatenate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is not a regular array since each dimension have different range depending on the observed axis (i.e., it can't be geometrically represented as a cube - your picture is not a `(n,n,n)` array).

Anyways, in the somewhat lengthy following snippet, we create a (5,5,5) test 3D array from which the (3,3,3) array can be sampled. Then we consecutively concatenate to obtain the original array, after which we mask the unwanted cells so the output is what your picture shows. Note that you can replace logic operations with `+` or `*` when using boolean Numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

# Define dummy 3D field
n = 5
xx, yy, zz = np.ogrid[0:n, 0:n, 0:n]
field = np.sin(xx) + np.cos(yy) + np.tan(zz)

# Indices of 3 innermost elements - to form (3,3,3) array
i1, i2 = n//2 - 1, n//2 + 1
# Inner 3D array
subfield = np.copy(field)[i1:i2+1, i1:i2+1, i1:i2+1]

# Indices of "inferior" pads
x1 = y1 = z1 = np.arange(i1 - 1, i1)
# Indices of "superior" pads
x2 = y2 = z2 = np.arange(i2 + 1, i2 + 2)

# Padding in axis 0 (x)
padded = np.concatenate((field[x1, i1:i2+1, i1:i2+1], subfield))
padded = np.concatenate((padded, field[x2, i1:i2+1, i1:i2+1]))
# Padding in axis 1 (y)
padded = np.concatenate((field[i1-1:i2+2, y1, i1:i2+1], padded), axis = 1)
padded = np.concatenate((padded, field[i1-1:i2+2, y2, i1:i2+1]), axis = 1)
# Padding in axis 2 (z)
padded = np.concatenate((field[i1-1:i2+2, i1-1:i2+2, z1], padded), axis = 2)
padded = np.concatenate((padded, field[i1-1:i2+2, i1-1:i2+2, z2]), axis = 2)

# Check padded array is equal to original 3D array
print(np.all(padded == field))

## We now mask unwanted cells
indices = np.indices(padded.shape)
idx1, idx2 = indices == 0, indices == n - 1

xi, xf = idx1[0], idx2[0]
yi, yf = idx1[1], idx2[1]
zi, zf = idx1[2], idx2[2]

# Logical operations to mask proper slices
xm = (xi + xf) * (yi + yf + zi + zf)            # masking in axis 0
ym = (yi + yf) * (xi + xf + zi + zf)            # masking in axis 1
zm = (zi + zf) * (yi + yf + xi + xf)            # masking in axis 2

mask = xm + ym + zm
# Masked (5,5,5) array
masked_padded = np.ma.masked_where(mask, padded)
```

By the way, there must be more elegant ways to achieve the same result, but I have not used Numpy's advanced indexing that much :P